# What does --strip-components -C mean in tar?

Tags: directory, tar, path

I want to make sure I understand the following code:

```
tar xvzf FILE --exclude-from=exclude.me --strip-components 1 -C DESTINATION
```

which was posted in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535763/149572).

From `man tar`:

> `--strip-components=NUMBER`
>   
>   strip NUMBER leading components from file names on extraction
>
> `-C`, `--directory=DIR`
>   
>   change to directory DIR

I didn't understand the manual explanation for `--strip-components`.

About `-C`, I understood that it means something like "put stripped components in a noted directory."

What does `--strip-components -C` mean?

Comment: May be a duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/575261/4778

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The fragment of manpage you included in your question comes from man
for GNU tar. GNU is a software project that prefers *info* manuals
over manpages.  In fact, tar manpage [has been added to the GNU tar
source code tree only in
2014](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/commit/?id=f5048215892c1bf6cf602c41146c556f60a63a51)
and it still is just a reference, not a full-blown manual with
examples.  You can invoke a full info manual with `info tar`, it's
also available online
[here](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html).  It contains
several examples of `--strip-components` usage, the relevant fragments
are:

> `--strip-components=number`
>
> Strip given number of leading components from file names before extraction.
>
> For example, if archive `archive.tar' contained `some/file/name', then running
>
> `tar --extract --file archive.tar --strip-components=2`
>
> would extract this file to file `name'.

and:

> `--strip-components=number`
>
> Strip given number of leading components from file names before extraction.
>
> For example, suppose you have archived whole `/usr' hierarchy to a tar archive named `usr.tar'. Among other files, this archive contains `usr/include/stdlib.h', which you wish to extract to the current working directory. To do so, you type:
>
> `$ tar -xf usr.tar --strip=2 usr/include/stdlib.h`
>
> The option `--strip=2' instructs tar to strip the two leading components (`usr/' and `include/') off the file name.

---

**That said;**

There are other implementations of tar out there, for example [FreeBSD
tar manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tar(1)) has a
different explanation of this command:

> `--strip-components count`
>
> Remove the specified number of leading path elements. Pathnames
>            with fewer elements will be silently skipped. Note that the
>            pathname is edited after checking inclusion/exclusion patterns
>            but before security checks.

In other words, you should understand a Unix path as a sequence of
elements separated by `/` (unless there is only one `/`).

**Here is my own example** (other examples are available in the info manual I linked to above):

Let's create a new directory structure:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c
```

Path `a/b/c` is composed of 3 elements: `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Create an empty file in this directory and put it into .tar archive:

```
$ touch a/b/c/FILE
$ tar -cf archive.tar a/b/c/FILE
```

`FILE` is a 4th element of `a/b/c/FILE` path.

List contents of archive.tar:

```
$ tar tf archive.tar
a/b/c/FILE
```

You can now extract archive.tar with `--strip-components` and an
argument that will tell it how many path elements you want to be removed from the `a/b/c/FILE` when extracted. Remove an original `a` directory:

```
rm -r a
```

Extract with `--strip-components=1` - only `a` has not been recreated:

```
$ tar xf archive.tar --strip-components=1
$ ls -Al
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 10240 Mar 26 15:41 archive.tar
drwxr-xr-x 3 ja users  4096 Mar 26 15:43 b
$ tree b
b
└── c
    └── FILE

1 directory, 1 file
```

With `--strip-components=2` you see that `a/b` - 2 elements have not
been recreated:

```
$ rm -r b
$ tar xf archive.tar --strip-components=2
$ ls -Al
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 10240 Mar 26 15:41 archive.tar
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja users  4096 Mar 26 15:46 c
$ tree c
c
└── FILE

0 directories, 1 file
```

With `--strip-components=3` 3 elements `a/b/c` have not been recreated
and we got `FILE` in the same level directory in which we run `tar`:

```
$ rm -r c
$ tar xf archive.tar --strip-components=3
$ ls -Al
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users     0 Mar 26 15:39 FILE
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 10240 Mar 26 15:41 archive.tar
```

---

`-C` option tells tar to change to a given directory before running a
requested operation, extracting but also archiving.  In [this
comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535772/what-does-strip-components-c-means#comment1070678_535775)
you asked:

> Asking tar to do cd: why cd? I mean to ask, why it's not just mv?

Why do you think that `mv` is better? To what directory would you like
to extract tar archive first:

- /tmp - what if it's missing or full?
- "$TMPDIR" - what if it's unset, missing or full?
- current directory - what if user has no `w` permission, just `r` and
  `x`?
- what if a temporary directory, whatever it is already contained
  files with the same names as in `tar` archive and extracting would
  overwrite them?
- what if a temporary directory, whatever it is didn't support Unix
  filesystems and all info about ownership, executable bits etc. would
  be lost?

Also notice that `-C` is a common `change directory` option in other
programs as well, [Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) and
[make](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make) are first that come to my
mind.

Answer (score 22):

The `--strip-components` option is for modifying the filenames of extracted files.  `--strip-components <N>` means "remove the first `<N>` components of the filename", where "components" is referring to parts of the path separated by `/`.

If you have a filename `foo/bar/baz`, then with `--strip-components 1` the extracted file would be named `bar/baz`.

---

The `-C` option just means "change directory".  If you use `-C /some/other/place` you are effectively asking `tar` to `cd /some/other/place` before extracting files. This generally means that files would be extracted relative to `/some/other/place`.

Comment: `--strip-components` doesn't have any impact over *what* gets extracted. The only thing it does is modify filenames.

Comment: I now re read the answer and I think I still miss, or at least become confused, about what is being done; I now offer bounty which I offer, in part, for editing and helping others in similar situation and myself, to ensure understanding.

Comment: Asking `tar` to do `cd`: why `cd`? I mean to ask, why it's not just `mv`?

Answer (score 4):

To supplement the good answer by [larsks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535775/257802), to try to help clear up the confusion around the `-C` option:

The `tar` man page states for the `-C` option:

```
-C, --directory=DIR
              Change  to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is
              order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.
```

so, it is not like `mv` - it is literally telling `tar` to change to a different working directory. Also note the point that the order matters. So:

```
tar r -f archive.tar -C /path file1 file2
```

would append files `file1` and `file2` at the location `/path` to `archive.tar`, whilst

```
tar r -f archive.tar file1 file2 -C /path file3 file4
```

would append `file1` and `file2` from the current working directory and then `file3` and `file4` from the `/path` location.

`--strip-components` and `-C` are independent and unrelated options to `tar`. The first affects the folder structure of the archived files, once they are extracted, and `-C` specifies the working directory that `tar` is using to specify files that are external to the archive.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure what I can say by way of explanation
that hasn’t been covered by the other answers. 
Instead, I’ll try to help you with examples.

[Arkadiusz Drabczyk gives the example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535772/80216#575121) from [the GNU tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_51.html)
where your archive includes a large directory tree (e.g., all of `/usr`):

```
$ tar -cf usr.tar  /usr
```

and you want to drill down into the archive
and extract a file from a low-level subdirectory:

```
$ tar -xf usr.tar --strip=2 usr/include/stdlib.h
```

What the manual doesn’t spell out is that, if you say

```
$ tar -xf usr.tar           usr/include/stdlib.h
```

then `tar` will create a `usr` directory in the current directory,
and an `include` subdirectory in `usr`,
and then extract `stdlib.h` into `./usr/include`. 
If that’s the result you want, then fine; use that command. 
But, if you want `stdlib.h` in the current directory, you’ll need to

```
$ mv usr/include/stdlib.h .
```

and then probably `rmdir -p usr/include`. 
It’s doable, but it’s tedious. 
`--strip=2` saves you a lot of typing.

---

`-C` can also be used with the `c` (lower-case C) option
(creating an archive), and that might be easier to understand. 
Suppose John, Kate, Larry and Mary are collaborating on writing a book;
they are writing Chapters 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively. 
John and Kate (only) are using the same computer,
and they want to archive what they’ve done so far
to send to the other authors. 
You could do either of the following:

```
  (cd to some suitable directory)
$ tar cf chap12.tar /home/john/chap1 /home/kate/chap2
```

or

```
$ cd /home
$ tar cf /tmp/chap12.tar john/chap1 kate/chap2
```

But these create an archive that encodes
the `john/` and `kate/` directory paths. 
***If you do that, that would be a reason for Larry and Mary
to use `--strip=2` or `--strip=1` when they extract the archive.*** 
If you want to save them that bother
(and/or keep your names out of the archive; e.g., for privacy reasons),
then you can

```
  (cd to some suitable directory)
$ tar cf chap12.tar -C /home/john chap1 -C /home/kate chap2
```

and then the archive will show just the `chap1` and `chap2` directories.