# How can I extract a specific file from an tar archive into the current directory?

Tags: tar

I can extract a specific file from a tar archive like this:

```
tar xvf gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6.tar.gz gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6/bin/gh
```

This extracts to the current directory, but the `gh` file is still within the directory structure in the archive. Is there a way to have the file extract into the current or any given directory instead?

Comment: If your system uses GNU tar, this may help [What does --strip-components -C mean in tar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535772/what-does-strip-components-c-mean-in-tar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gnu tar, try

```
tar xvf gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6.tar.gz --one-top-level=. gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6/bin/gh
```

or, as suggested in comments, instead of `--one-top-level`, use  `--strip-components=2` for this example, but that might not work if you want to extract multiple files from different directories.

Comment: That made no difference and the file was still extracted to within the directory structure. `--strip-components` worked though.⎄n

Answer (score 1):

**Answer using GNU tar:**

```
tar xvf gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6.tar.gz gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6/bin/gh -O > gh
```

You can try the code block above. `O` option is making output stdout. So you combine with redirection operator.

Comment: This works,  but be aware that file permissions for executables are lost and change to umask default. `--strip-components` is probably best for single files.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, for a single file or for multiple files located on the same level in the archive, the option `--strip-components=N`, works fine.
The other GNU `tar` option that works for any number of files located anywhere in the archive is `--xform` (or [`--transform`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#transform)).
It allows modifying file names using a `sed`-like replace expression of the form:

```
s/regexp/replace/[flags]
```

so in your case the expression `s|.*/||` removes all leading components from the file path i.e.

```
tar xvf gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6.tar.gz  --xform='s|.*/||' gh_2.5.1_linux_armv6/bin/gh
```

extracts only the `gh` file (without any parent directories) in the current directory. Also, one can see the requested transformations applied with the `--show-transformed-names` option e.g. dry run:

```
tar -tf archive.tar.gz --xform='s|.*/||' --show-transformed-names
```

This can be combined with other options, e.g. extract based on pattern, to another directory:

```
tar -xvzf archive.tar.gz --xform='s|.*/||' -C dest_dir --wildcards --no-anchored 'match*'
```