# How to rename top folder in tarball while extracting?

Tags: tar

If I have a tar.gz archive containing a single folder named like `<somename>-<somenumber>`, how do I extract it so it unpacks into a folder called `<somename>`?

For example, the file `somearchive.tar.gz` contains a top-level folder `somearchive-0.1.2`, and I tried something like:

```
tar xvfz somearchive.tar.gz --transform s/[a-zA-Z]+\-[0-9\.]+/somearchive/
```

but that extracts it to the default folder.

Comment: At least with GNU tar, the `--transform` option expects a GNU basic regular expression I think - so you need to backslash escape the `+` in order to make it a quantifier. Try `--transform 's/[a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9.]\+/somearchive/'` (`-` *doesn't* need escaping, and `.` doesn't when inside `[]`)

Comment: I'd advise against that.  The traditional way of doing things is to extract the archive and symlink `somename -> somename-somenumber`.  That way you can easily rollback if needed.  If that is not an issue, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/535763/364705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As steeldriver pointed out, `tar --transform` expects a sed replace expression, which uses basic regular expression syntax, not extended regular expression syntax, and in particular the “one or more” operator is `\+`, not `+`. See
[Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

```
tar xvfz somearchive.tar.gz --transform 's/^[a-zA-Z]\+-[0-9.]\+/somearchive/'
```

Or you could make it simply

```
tar xvfz somearchive.tar.gz --transform 's!^[^/]*!somearchive!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Gilles's answer perfectly fit my question. However, I also found this alternative works as well:

```
mkdir somearchive
tar xvfz somearchive.tar.gz --strip 1 -C somearchive
```